# Ayuda con un método de arboles representados como listas generalizadas

Tags: java

vengo a pedir ayuda. nesecito hacer un metodo que inserter un nuevo registro al árbol, se recibe el dato y el padre. el metodo es recursivo

```
    public void insertar_adelante( int padre, int dato){
    Nodo q;
    if(raiz == null){
        q = new Nodo(0,dato);
        raiz = q;
    }else{
        insertarRecursivo(raiz, raiz, padre,dato);
    }

}

public void insertarRecursivo(Nodo p, Nodo ant, int padre, int hijo) {
    if (p != null) {
        if (p.getSw() == 0) {
            if (p.getDato() == padre) {
                if (p == ant) {
                    Nodo q, z;
                    q = p;
                    while (q.getLiga() != null) {
                        q = q.getLiga();
                    }
                    z = new Nodo(0, hijo);
                    q.setLiga(z);

                } else {
                    Nodo q, z;

                    q = new Nodo(0, padre);
                    z = new Nodo(0, hijo);
                    q.setLiga(z);
                    p.setLh(q);
                    p.setDato(0);
                    p.setSw(1);
                }
            }
        } else {
            insertarRecursivo(p.getLh(), p.getLh(), padre, hijo);
        }
        insertarRecursivo(p.getLiga(), ant, padre, hijo);
    }

}
```

en el main tengo esto

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    ArbolNareo x = new ArbolNareo();
    x.insertar_adelante(0, 4);
    x.insertar_adelante(0, 5);
    x.mostrar();

}
```

y solo me muestra el 4 con este metodo:

```
public void mostrar(){
    mostrardatos(raiz);
}
public void mostrardatos(Nodo p){
    Nodo q = p;
    while(q != null){
        if(q.getSw() == 0){
            System.out.println(""+q.getDato());
        }else{
            mostrardatos(q.getLh());
        }
        q = q.getLiga();
    }
}
```

creo que el problema esta en el método de insertar o en el main no lo se.. ayuda plzzz

Comment: Pero cuál es el problema?

Comment: no se entiende mucho el codigo, los atributos de nodo en particular no tienen un nombre claro. En tu uso en particular de esa estructura la siguiente linea `if (p.getDato() == padre)` siempre sera falsa, porque no hay ningun dato 0 insertado segun tu main. Si hicieras `x.insertar_adelante(0, 0);` antes en cambio, verias otro comportamiento. Aunque probablemente aun no sea el correcto.